# How to access to wwv_flow_request_verifications

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle-apex

I want to create a custom captcha in oracle apex.
I find a tutorial, in that tutorial he uses wwv_flow_request_verifications table, but when I want to use that table, apex shows me this error: this table or view does not exists.
This is my code:

```
Declare
vCount NUMBER :=0;
BEGIN
SELECT 1 into vCount FROM vww_flow_request_verifications
WHERE session_id = :APP_SESSION 
END;
```

This is just an example
How should I access to wwv_flow_request_verifications table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you are connected as the APEX schema, you will need to prefix the table with your APEX schema name which will vary based on the version of APEX you have installed.

I have APEX 19.2 installed so my query would look like this:

```sql
select * from apex_190200.wwv_flow_request_verifications;
```

Comment: My oracle apex version is 20.1 and its schema is apex_200100. I have used apex_200100.wwv_flow_request_verifications but it doesn't work too. Should I execute any grant command for that?

Comment: Typically `GRANT` or `READ` privileges would be needed to select from tables that begin with *wwv_flow* so if you do not have privileges to select from the table, then you would need to grant the privilege explicitly.

Comment: What grant I need exactly? please tell me the exact command. Thanks

Comment: `GRANT READ ON apex_200100.wwv_flow_request_verifications TO your_user`

Comment: How could I find my apex user? I login with admin but it says admin is not exists

Comment: You need to connect to the database as a user who has privileges to run the grant then, such as `SYS` or `APEX_200100`